# Count occurence of string in a series type column of data frame in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column in data frame which looks like below

[image]

How do i calculate frequency of each word. For ex: The word 'doorman' appears in 4 rows so i need the word along with its frequency i.e doorman = 4.
This needs to be done for each and every word.

Please advise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can first flat list of lists in column and then use `Counter`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'features':[['a','b','b'],['c'],['a','a']]})

print (df)
    features
0  [a, b, b]
1        [c]
2     [a, a]

from  itertools import chain
from collections import Counter

print (Counter(list(chain.from_iterable(df.features))))
Counter({'a': 3, 'b': 2, 'c': 1})
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. Quick question, How do i sort the list by frequency and pick top 5 words with maximum frequency. Thanks again

Comment: give me a sec, please

Comment: I think you can use `print (Counter(list(chain.from_iterable(df.features))).most_common(5))`

Comment: thanks i was able to do it by following code sorted(df1,key=df1.get)

import operator

sorted_x = sorted(df1.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
sorted_x.reverse()

Comment: Yes, it is another solution.

Comment: yes most_common works as well and is much cleaner. Thanks again